# .net ascx control not retaining value on postback (mojoPortal)

Tags: asp.net, mojoportal

I'm making a custom module for [mojoPortal CMS](http://www.mojoportal.com/) which needs to allow the client to add an affiliate into the database.  As far as I can tell, this requires creating a .ascx file and then installing that using the administration toolbar in the Web interface to get it to a point where I can put it into a page, as http://www.mojoportal.com/hello-world-developer-quick-start.aspx.

The form is simple enough, but the values in the text boxes just stay empty when I submit, though the file upload works fine. The code:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Company Name" AssociatedControlID="CompanyName">
</asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="CompanyName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Company Description" AssociatedControlID="CompanyDescription"></asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="CompanyDescription" TextMode="MultiLine" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Company Logo" AssociatedControlID="CompanyLogo"></asp:Label>
<asp:FileUpload ID="CompanyLogo" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="SubmitButton" runat="server" Text="Add Affiliate" />
```

EnableViewState for the page and the controls is enabled

The text box is not set to ReadOnly, and there is no funky JavaScript dynamically modifying elements (at least, I didn't set any).

I can work around this by using HTML elements, and get the values using Request.Form.  The information is actually there, I can see it in the Request.Form, but I would have to get that by something like Request.Form[CompanyName.ClientId.Replace("_","$")] or Request.Form[6] which both seem very messy and IIRC aren't really the way things are supposed to roll in .NET.  Besides, having worked until 3 last night, I really want to know what the answer is now!

Any thoughts anyone?

Answer (score 0):

What I had done was not created a click event for the button, relying on the fact that it was posting to the server (like I would in PHP).  Oops!  When I added a click event, then the text boxes retained their value when I was within that method.